# Any way to highlight current date column in my google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, highlight

I have this planning sheet I am working on: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GQpZh0MOotBl_iAucGm_LnK8shIKjjgukGqaFVvGKF8/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see events are planned out on a sort of calendar look.
I will be using this every day and I would like it to highlight the current date to me automatically. I've highlighted today's date manually.

Do you see any way to do this?

It does not need to be the whole column it can just be the day number and week of day on the top if it's easier.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me regarding this!

Thanks a lot.

Balint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to use [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?hl=en)
on the column with the dates. Rule should be "Date is today". Choose a color to your likings.

Comment: Upvoting this because it's a much easier way to do it now - no custom formula required.

Answer (score 13):

I found this question when searching for a way to highlight a whole column/row.

Here's the way to do it:

Apply to range:  `A1:Z1000`  (this is the range of all columns/rows including the dates)

- Format cells if...:  `[Custom formula is]`
- Formula (for columns):  `=A$1=TODAY()`
- Formula (for rows): `=$A1=TODAY()`

The dollar sign ($) will keep the reference cell fixed. So if the formula uses A$1 it takes A1, B1, C1 etc to look for the date and then highlights the entire column A, B, C etc.

If the formula uses $A1 it takes A1, A2, A3 etc to look for the date and then highlights the entire row 1, 2, 3 etc.

Just make sure that "range" covers the entire rectangle of cells and not just one date. It's easy to adapt if your dates are in a different row/column.

Hope this helps the next person who comes here with a similar problem :)

Comment: Thanks very much! This is very helpful and worked perfectly for my sheet. Now I can highlight the whole row when the first cell contains the current date.

Comment: Thanks, have been looking for this for years. I think this should be re-approved as the new best answer.